# Unhandled Runtime Error with search function in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm doing an live search it works fine with populate all user when I type it input but when I remove all the words in input it's giving me this error.

Here is my error look like.

[image]

Here is my code in ResultList.js:

```
const generateSkillObjNodes = (userObj, skillName, keyInd) => {
  return (
    <UserFound
      userObj={userObj}
      key={`${userObj.public_user_id}${keyInd}`}
      skill={skillName}
    />
  );
};


const ResultsList = ({ resultsArr, resultsType }) => {
  // Determine list to render

  if (resultsType === "users") {
    return resultsArr.map((userObj, index) => (
      <UserFound userObj={userObj} key={`${userObj.public_user_id}${index}`} />
    ));
  } else if (resultsType === "skills") {
    return resultsArr.map((skillsObj) => {
      return skillsObj.Users.map((userObj, index) => generateSkillObjNodes(userObj, skillsObj.skill, index)); // note: this logic may end up duplicating users if they match on more than once skill
    });
  } else {
    // For team list, first check and make sure there are results
    if (resultsArr.length > 0) {
      // Map over the data
      return resultsArr.map((teamObj) => (
        <TeamFound teamObj={teamObj} key={teamObj.public_team_id} />
      ));
    } else {
      // No results to render, display no results message
      return (
        <div className="container--no_results">
          <h3 className="header header--search_results">No teams found</h3>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
};

export default ResultsList;
```

Here is my code for search function:

```
const SearchBar = ({
  linktoPage,
  searchForTerm,
  placeHolderText = "Search members or teams",
}) => {
  // Search state
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    // Update state with input text
    event.preventDefault();
    setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
    try {   
      if (linktoPage) {
        // Go to page and pass query
        goToPage();
      } else {
        // Don't change pages, but pass term to search method
        searchForTerm(event.target.value);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(err);
    }
  };

  const goToPage = () => {
    // Go to search page and pass along the search term.
    Router.push({
      pathname: "/search",
      query: { term: `${searchTerm}` },
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="search_wrapper">
      <input
        className="input input--search_input"
        type="search"
        name="q"
        placeholder={placeHolderText}
        aria-label="Search bar"
        onInput={handleChange}
        pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+"
        required
      />
      <Button className="input input--search" style={{ color: "white", backgroundColor: "#00B790" }} type="submit" >
        <SearchRoundedIcon />
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchBar;
```

Here is how my page look like:
[image]

How can I fix this error?
Thank you for helping me out. I am new to react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by `resultsArr` who change type when the search is empty, that's why the error says `resultsArr.map is not a function`

Maybe this will avoid the error:

```
return Array.isArray(resultsArr) ? resultsArr.map((userObj, index) => (
      <UserFound userObj={userObj} key={`${userObj.public_user_id}${index}`} />
    )) : 'No results';
```

But the best thing would be to understand what happens to `resultsArr` when there are is no `searchTerm`

Comment: If it still throws that error it means that `resultArray` is not falsy value, try to change the condition with `Array.isArray(resultsArr) ? ... : ... `

Comment: How can I change it

Comment: Thanks alot. That works. I reallly appreciate your time. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

The possible problem could be when you delete all the letters/words `resultsArr` becomes `undefined` and that causes the error I would suggest wherever you are calling `<ResultsList />` check for `resultsArr` first and then call the component, such as:

```
{resultsArr && <ResultsList resultsArr={resultsArr} resultsType={resultsType}/>}
```